# Discord JS Giveaway command, output

Tags: javascript, output, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around it am I'm sure it's an easy fix i'm over looking but could anyone help make the output reasonable.

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

console.log(`${message.member} ran the "GiveAway" command`);

var item = "";
var time;
var winnerCount
let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
//-- f!giveaway 1(winnerCount) 60(seconds) Item Giveaway

for (var i = 3; i < messageArray.length; i++){
  item += (messageArray[i] + " ");
}
winnerCount = Number(messageArray[1]);
time = Number(messageArray[2]);


var giveEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
giveEmbed.setDescription(item);
var embedSent = await message.channel.send(giveEmbed);
embedSent.react("");
setTimeout(function() {


  var peopleReacted = embedSent.reactions.get("").users;
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length);
  var winners = [];
  var winnerMsg = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++){
    winnerMsg += (winners[i].toString() + " ");
  }
  var haveHas = "has";
  if (winners.length == 1){
    haveHas = "has";
  }
  else{
    haveHas = "have";
  }
  message.channel.send(winnerMsg + " " + haveHas + ` won ${item}`);
}, time * 1000); //--conversting seconds into miliseconds
}
```

It's not catching the user and displaying it with the output

Comment: You really need to explain what your code does, and what you expect the output to be, so that we don't have to read your code to try and decipher it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to do is get the people who reacted. I think the reason it’s not working is because messages need to be in the cache to be edited or to be able to get reactions from it. I suggest you have a separate command that, when done, stores the names of the people that did it. Then when the timer runs out it will take the data stored and raffle it from there.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lorokh Yeah, the output is needing to check the players that have reacted to the "giveaway" embed then send another message saying "x has won (item)". The output right now just says "have won (item). It's not catching the users, and the "have" is suppose to be has with only one person is suppose to be chosen.

Comment: So did my answer help or is there still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem lies in the `setTimeout` function. Let's break down your code.

```
var peopleReacted = embedSent.reactions.get("").users;
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length);
```

First of all, your code fetches all the users which have reacted with a "" and it stores it in an array `peopleReacted`. After that you get a random index from the `peopleReacted` array which I assume you later want to use to get the random winner.

```
var winners = [];
var winnerMsg = "";
for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++){
    winnerMsg += (winners[i].toString() + " ");
}
```

Then we get to this block, where I think your problem lays. Here you create an **empty** array called `winners`. Then you have a `for` loop for that empty array. Since the array is empty, the `for` loop won't fire a single time. Therefore, `winnerMsg` stays empty and you don't get a user's name.

```
var haveHas = "has";
if (winners.length == 1){
    haveHas = "has";
}
else{
    haveHas = "have";
}
```

After that, this happends. You define a variable which you want to give the value of either "has" or "have" depending on the amount of winners. You check for the length of the `winners` array, but as we already discussed earlier, that array is empty. An empty array has a length of `0`, so it will go into the `else` statement, explaining why the result has the word "have" instead of "has".

So here is my attempt at fixing your problem. Give this code a try and let me know what happends.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var peopleReacted = embedSent.reactions.get("").users;
  var winners = [];

  // Checks if fewer people reacted than the winnerCount allows users to win
  if (peopleReacted.length >= winnerCount) {
    winners = peopleReacted;
  } else {
    // Gets as many random users from the peopleReacted as winnerCount allows users to win
    for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length);
      winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
      // After adding a user to winners, remove that item from the array to prevent him from winning multiple times
      peopleReacted.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  var winnerMsg = "User(s) ";
  for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++){
    // Add each winner to the winnerMsg
    winnerMsg += (winners[i].toString() + ", ");
  }

  var haveHas;
  if (winners.length === 1){
    haveHas = "has";
  }
  else {
    haveHas = "have";
  }
  message.channel.send(`${winnerMsg} ${haveHas} won ${item}`);
}, time * 1000); //--conversting seconds into miliseconds
```